# Are 'par' and 'pseq' good for data parallelism?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Are 'par' and 'pseq' good for data parallelism or it is made for task-parallelism solely?

For example, if it is used to separate working over list of data items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is yes. You can, for example, evaluate the elements of the list in parallel using the `parList` strategy from [Control.Parallel.Strategies](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/2.2.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html). If your data items are very cheap to compute, you may want a more coarse-grained parallelism, like in `parListChunk` strategy.